# maven downloading file on every run 'install' target called

Tags: build, maven-3

I am using appfuse-spring 2.2.snapshot artifact in my project. I am using  maven is 3 .

When I run maven target 'install' every time download the same jar and dependency file.

How can I avoid to download the same files again and again.

for example 
Downloading: http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/appfuse-snapshots/org/appfuse/appfuse-web/2.2.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml

I don't want to download the jar file again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you see the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why it's will download again and again? If it's always downloading maybe something is wrong because once the library is in your local repository it shouldn't need to download anything unless a dependency changes.

If you want to disable the download, use `-o` (offline) option in your `mvn` command:

```
mvn install -o
```

More: [Maven Command Line Options](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you download the snapshot. Maven check a snapshot dependency each build (and if require downloads it).
Please avoid depend of snapshots. 
Please find your deps in the releases repository:
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/appfuse-releases/

Answer (score 0):

Old question but probably the solution would have been to check the "updatePolicy" for the repo, its possibly set to "always".